# File uploading by drag and drop with progress bar in asp.net

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-3.5

I want drag and drop area in which we need to just drag and drop file/multiple files which we want to upload from desktop and files get uploaded automatically showing progress bar as well. For cancellation of uploading process, cancel button and delete button for uploaded file must be shown. After file being uploded, files can be downloaded as well from the same place where we have uploaded files.

I have found many of jQuery plugin but none of them provides all functions.

I am new to asp.net and jQuery area. Please guide me.
I am using asp.net 3.5 Framwork and visual studio 2008.
thanks in advance.

Comment: did you even searched it want you are looking ?? check this out http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Maybe you are looking at a wrong place.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=460142&av=660697  try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jquery Upload File Demo http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/[^]

and then add download functionality

such a way

download functionality in jquery File upload such a way

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/563453/downloadplusfunctionalityplusinplusjqueryplusFilep

Answer (score 0):

You can use silverlight multi file uploader. Its provide best way to upload multiple file with client side validation on file type and file size etc.Also we can easily show progress bar(Uploading) in silverlight.

see this link.

http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is based on MVC model. I am not using MVC framework in asp.net